# OPENGL clip coordinate

Tags: opengl, clip

I have a question for opengl clip coordinate. For example, a triangle, three vetices, now have transformed to camera coordinate, multiply with perspective projection matrix to clip coordinate, begin to clip, 
    `-w=<x<=w, -w=<y<=w, -w=<z<=w,`
does x,y,z,w mean to each vertex's clip coordinate? So w may not be same in these three vertices?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, that w will vary per vertex. Most people imagine the clip space as the cube [-1,1]^3. However, that is not the clip space, but the normalized device space (NDC). You get from clip space to NDC by doing the perspective divide, so dividing each vertex by it's w component. So, in NDC, that clip condition would transform to -1 <= x/w <= 1. However, the clipping cannot be done in NDC (withpout extra information).

The problem here is that points which lie behind the camera would appear in front of the camera in NDC space. Think about it: x/w is the same as -x/-w. With a typical GL projection matrix, w_clip == z_eye of the vertex. Also, a point that lies in the camera plane (the plane parallel to the projection plane, but going through the camera itself) will have w=0 and you can't do any clipping after that divide. The solution is to always do the clipping before the divide, hence the clip space is called "clip space"...

Comment: perspective projection will have w_clip = z_eye, but orthographic projection is there any method to save depth information?

Comment: @yewei: for orthogonal projection, w_clip is typically w_object, and that is a) totally under your control and b) typically 1.0. But I do not know what you mean by "save depth information" in this context.

Comment: I mean after orthogonal projection, how to save z_eye? I think in perspective projection, w_clip = z_eye, this is also a method to save original depth information in order to do depth test in z-buffer.

Comment: @yewei: After projection to clip space and divide by w, you still have three coordinates x,y,z. These are converted to window space, x_win,y_win is used to rasterize the primitves on screen, and z_win is used for the depth buffer. It does not matter if you use a perspective or orthogonal projection. And you can also recalculate eye/world/object space from those 3d window space coords, if you know the matrices which were used. But I really do not know what you do mean by "save z_eye". You can push it dircetly to the shader, if you want to. Or you can recalculate it from window space.

Comment: @derhass - Thanks for the very useful comment! I still have a doubt, could you please help? In basically all the sources I found online ([linking one for reference](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html)) the NDC space is shown as a cube. How should I think of the Clip space as? Is it a cube as well, or is it a perspective frustum as the eye space (since inside of it we can represent points at infinity)? And is it correct to think of the operation that goes from clip to to NDC as mapping a ray in the first into a point in the second, or is it 1 to 1?

Comment: @Matteo: I don't think that  there is an intuitive way to visualize clip space. It ia a four-dimensional space after all. It might help imaging a 3d space which is the projective extension of uecidiean 2d space, just to get the idea, but it is still not intuitive.  The perspective divide can map points at infinity to some finite point, but a ray will still be a set of points, not a single point.

Comment: @derhass - Thanks for the response. As a follow-up, suppose all the objects were inside the clip space, would that be equivalent to saying that the clip space and the NDC are the same? I.e. the fourth coordinate is actually 1 for all vertices. And finally, why is this the case: ` With a typical GL projection matrix, w_clip == z_eye of the vertex`?

Comment: @Matteo: What do you mean by "inside the clip space". All those spaces, object space, eye space, clip space, NDC, ... are conceptually _infinite_. You probably mean inside the viewing volume. (Note that one can use  projection matrices where the far plane is at infinity, so the viewing volume is infinite in eye space, but mapped to the finite cube in NDC) . When you have clip space w =1 for all vertices, this implies that you use a orthogonal projection, and then, yes, NDC and clip coords are identical.

Comment: @Matteo: If you want perspective - things appearing smaller when they are farther away - you will basically have to scale them depeinding on the distance to the viewers' plane. If you do the math, you'll end up with a simple intersection theorem, telling you that you can just divide x and y by -z, if the camera is at origin and looking into -z direction, which was GL's default eye space convention. That division is done by the clip space -> NDC transform, and the projection matrix is responsible for setting w appropriately. The rest of the projection martix just deals with the FOV/depth range.